# Permission denied on .dll file when installing package

Tags: r, windows, dll

New job gave me a fresh Windows laptop where I am struggling (to say the very least) to set up  a fresh R environment. Specifically, when developing a package, the commmand `Install and Restart` exits abruptly due to permission issues on a specific `.dll` file.

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source --install-tests curl

* installing to library 'C:/R/R-Library'
* installing *source* package 'curl' ...
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'C:/R/R-Library/curl'
* restoring previous 'C:/R/R-Library/curl'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\R\R-Library\00LOCK-curl\curl\libs\x64\curl.dll to C:\R\R-Library\curl\libs\x64\curl.dll: Permission denied

Exited with status 1.
```

As a first attempt to ameliorate the issue, I've moved both my R installation and library at `C:/`. This obviously seems not to be enough.

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/R/R-Library"       "C:/R/R-4.0.3/library"
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252    LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

I am kind of lost as to where to look next. As a last shot in the dark I've tried to run RStudio with Admin right with no luck.

Comment: Experience the same problem after installing R 4.2.0. Still looking for a solution. I have experienced the same problem in the past and it has resolved after I have reinstalled Windows.

Comment: I have found a partial solution. Simply restart R-session prior to "Install and Restart". On Windows 10 I use "ctrl+shift+f10" and then "Install and Restart" does not cause this error message.

Comment: Restarting the session does not work in my case.

Comment: I have to "Terminate" the R-session to avoid this error (with R version 4.3.0 and RStudio 2023.03.0 Build 386).